# CSV file login system not working

Tags: python

```
import csv

def login():                                         #defining subroutine login
    searchusername = input("Enter your username: ")  #Login code
    searchpassword = input("Enter your password: ")

    csvreader = open("usercsv.csv", "r")
    for row in csvreader:
        details = row.split(",")
        if  details[0] == searchusername and details[1]== searchpassword:
            print("Login succesful")
        else:
            print("Login unsuccesful. Try again.")
            login()


    csvreader.close()
```

Hi all

I'm new to python as I have just started studying it at school.
My problem here is that I always get the login unsuccessful error message. Any tips on how to fix this?
Many Thanks

Comment: Well, unless the very first login in the CSV file is the one you're looking for, the comparison will be `false` on the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: You should iterate all the rows in the csv, if you found the username and the password tuple print succes text else after the loops ends print fail text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @David says, your loop will always try again unless the login is successful on the very first line.

Additionally, you should protect your code against errors by putting your file.close() in a `finally` block. `with` will do this automatically, safely closing the file when it goes out of scope!

Your code doesn't appear to make use of the `csv` module, but it may simply be used later in your code.

```
def login(backend_csv="usercsv.csv"):
    searchusername = input("Enter your username: ")
    searchpassword = input("Enter your password: ")

    with open(backend_csv, "r") as fh:
        for row in fh.read().split('\n'):
            if len(row) < 2:  # skip empty/trash rows
                continue
            details = row.split(",")
            try:
                if details[0] == searchusername and details[1] == searchpassword:
                    print("Login successful")
                    break  # escape from the for loop
            except IndexError:  # details did not have at least two members
                print("corrupt line in csv: {}".format(row))
        else:  # for loop did not break
            print("login failed: please try again")
            login(backend_csv=backend_csv)

    # csv closed here when with block goes out of scope
    # user login should be successful here!
```

You could further improve this with additional case handling, such as

- handling `IOError` which `open()` will raise for a missing csv file
- only permitting a known number of retries (decrement an argument by 1 and check for <1 at the start of your function)
- enumerating your rows, so you know which line was corrupt

As a final note, this is not a secure way to handle logins, please do not use this for anything other than learning/experimentation!

Comment: Thank you so much. As i say ive only just starting studying it and am still very much learning the basics! This will help me no end. Thanks again

Comment: Anytime and best of luck! Off-topic/unrelated to your question and old .. but this may help you grow some deeper Python roots: http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html